# Change default query parameters

Tags: urls, query-variable

Hi I am using an exteral site which redirects to my wordpress site with some url parameters.  Unfortunately one of these is `m` which is causing a conflict which wordpress's native parameters and throwing a `404` not found.  is there any I can tell wordpress to ignore that parameter for a specific page?

Comment: It's better to not use the parameter on the external site.

Comment: Yes that would preferable, but it's not my site, so I need a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter `request` and unset `m` there, which will remove it from the query. This is a simple example that will remove it in all cases, you probably want to narrow the check down with something else, like checking if `pagename` is also set:

```
function wpd_request_filter( $request ){
    if( isset( $request['m'] ) ){
        unset( $request['m'] );
    }
    return $request;
}
add_filter( 'request', 'wpd_request_filter' );
```

You can `var_dump( $request )` in the filter to see what it contains for different types of requests.